# Регулярные выражения: включить и исключить символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Можно-ли используя регулярные выражения сделать так, чтобы включить все буквы: **[a-z]**, но исключить некоторые, например **[^ite]**. То есть в итоге должно получиться что-то вроде: **[a-z] & [^ite]**.

Сейчас приходит в голову два раза проверять символ на соответствие, сначала одному regex, потом другому.

Comment: Например, написать явно допустимые интервалы

    [a-df-hj-su-z]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/(?(?=[a-z])[^ite]|^$)/
```

Схема:

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

Пояснение:

```
Если [a-z], то [^ite] (выбрать из [a-z] все, кроме i, t и e), иначе ^$ (пустая строка)
```

В случае выполнения условия выборка будет проводится из того массива совпадений, по которому была проверка. В данном случае она будет ограничена латинскими буквами.

Вот тут можно **[посмотреть пример работы](http://regex101.com/r/uX3wE6)**.
А вот тут можно почитать подробнее об **[использовании условий в регулярных выражениях](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)**.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Видимо конструкция если-то не везде поддерживается, здесь (http://www.regexr.com/) не получилось, на Scala тоже, но вот такой вариант: (?=[a-z])[^ite] http://regex101.com/r/tX3lP5/ делает что мне нужно

Comment: @phpusr, проблема в том, что вы не указали, на каком языке программирования вам надо это реализовать. В зависимости от этого меняется способ реализации. В моем ответе используется PCRE синтаксис.

Comment: хотел добавить что чаще всего используется либа pcre.c в других языках, но не всегда включает расширенный набор возможностей к которому относиться конструкция (?(?=regex)then|else). Иногда нужно включать в самой обвертке. И else не есть обязательным тоесть можно просто (?(?=regex)then) так что городить |^$ это уже перебор

Comment: Большинство современных программеров эту запись никогда не поймут... Неужто в МГУ не могут придумать ничего проще... Ужос)

Answer (score 8):

Если первый массив символов соответствует символьному метосимволу, 
например **[a-z] == \pL**
то можно сделать просто так

```
[^\PLite]
```

На практике часто хотят все символы **\w** минус набор исключений **[^ite]**
то есть `[^\Wite]`

P.S. это решение на порядок быстрей отработает нежели lookahead. Обрати внимание что я в примере использую \w и \W, тоесть `[^\Wa]` это отрациние от отрицательного массива \W, значит найти все возможные символы из диапазно b-z (a-z минус a). А быстро это работает потому что работает "математика множест" **[a-z] - [a] = [b-z]**